# uiview like actionsheet

Tags: iphone, uiview, uiactionsheet, presentmodalviewcontroller

Is it possible to show uiview like actionsheet on presentmodalviewcontroller(i.e. that is uiview should go top but it should not go fully and it should be half) so that i view the last view controller on screen.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
sathish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [blog](http://ramin.firoozye.com/2009/09/29/semi-modal-transparent-dialogs-on-the-iphone/) entry will help what I think you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this

just take a new view and fix its frame according to ur requirment and then add on subview

Comment: self.view = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 200, 320, 330)] autorelease];

Comment: thanks for your quick reply.i added code self.view = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 200, 320, 330)] autorelease]; and put my code but size decreased but it doesnot show previous screen ghostrider.

Comment: uiview *newView = [[uiview alloc]initwithframe:cgrectmake(0,200,320.260); [self.view addsubview:newView];

Comment: Thanks ghost rider for your valuable suggestion